# NGINX returns 404 when accessing a defined location

Tags: nginx, server, http-status-code-404

I am experimenting with Nginx location block I don't understand why I've got a 404 when I try to access the index from a different location. Also if I try to access the index of the same root using a different location.

```
server {
        server_name test.com;
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/;

        location /gg {
                root /var/www/html/;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
        
        location /hi: {
               root /var/www/html/hicontent;
               index index.html index.htm;
        }

}
```

Of course, in both cases, there is an `index.html` file. Still some resource that are accessed in another location are not available if I try to set another location that is accessing the same resource.

Comment: You're using `root` so the path of the filename is constructed by concatenating the value of the `root` with the value of the URI. So `/gg/index.html` will be located at `/var/www/html/gg/index.html` and `/hi:/index.html` will be located at `/var/www/html/hicontent/hi:/index.html`. If the files are not there, Nginx will generate a 404 response.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks now I understand ,  I spent two hours in the documentation but I did not realize this.